# Access denied for all pages including admin in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

Recently I made following 2 changes in the admin, after that it show "You are not authorized to access this page" for all pages including admin panel. I do not know how to restore it.

The changes are

1) Enabled Web services modules of HAL, Basic Auth and Resful API

2) Admin > People > Permission, checked on the checkbox for some settings.

Right now only the header and footer is loading with above message for all pages including admin panel. Please help me to fix this.

Note : I tried by clearing browser cache and execute update.php but nothing works.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Tested on Drupal 8.0.6 and Drupal 8.1.0 (enabled these modules + turned on ALL permissions' checkboxes). I guess you should try to disable these 3 modules and set all permissions to the initial state manually editing database (don't know how to do it in D8, just a thought to google it).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. When I remove the htaccess in the root the homepage is loading properly but the inner pages are not loading (returns 404 error). When I add the .htaccess file in the root then it returns the 'Access denied' error.